# New Discussion not displaying in Discussion Board - Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-discussion-board

I am trying to create a discussion forum for my site on Sharepoint. I have added the 'Discussion Board' app in Site Contents.

I have created a new discussion, with text in the subject and body and have marked it as a question.

But when I click save, the content does not show up in the discussion board. All that shows up is a faded line across the page where the question should appear (Image of issue has been attached).

I have gone through the site settings, site contents, discussion board settings and cannot seem to find why this is happening.

Your help would be really appreciated

Thank you

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvKXM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be you have some custom css or JavaScript attached to the page that prevents the div containing the content to show. Or it could be some issue with the browser you are using. Try view the page with a different browser, and try using the browsers developer Tools to inspect the page to see if there is a hidden div with content in the pages source.

Comment: What version of SharePoint and browser are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010 and I have tried it in IE and Chrome but issue is the same

Comment: Are you sure it is SharePoint 2010? By the image you attached it looks like SharePoint 2013.

Comment: If you open the Discussion Board in Chrome, position the cursor over the faded line, do a mouse right click and select Inspect. Then the developer Tools will open and show the HTML for the faded line element. Copy and paste that HTML here so we can have a look at it.